# Error Database connection with user and password info

Tags: mysql, database, zend-framework

I have a connection to a data base and every time there is a problem connecting I get this error.

> ```
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '205.178.146.104' (4)' in /data/18/2/77/115/2566441/user/2813515/htdocs/ZendFramework-1.11.5/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:129 
> Stack trace: 
> #0 .../ZendFramework-1.11.5/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(129): PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=si...', 'xxx', 'xxx', Array) 
> #1 .../ZendFramework-1.11.5/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() 
> #2 .../ZendFramework-1.11.5/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(459): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() 
> #3 .../ZendFramework-1.11.5/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('DESCRIBE `user`', Array) 
> #4 .../ZendFramework-1.11.5/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysq in .../ZendFramework-1.11.5/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 144
> ```

The thing is that the database user and password are visible on the page in the error message. Is there a way that I can prevent PHP from showing that info? Or is this happening because I am set up a a developing instead of production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are on "developing" (exceptions are shown in browser)

- Solution 1: Use Production Environment ;)
- Solution 2: Change settings in application.ini
- Solution 3: Use an try/catch block for database connect

Answer (score 2):

It is a combination of both. In development, your showing your errors. Which is the primary reason your seeing that.

However, you can `catch` the exception by testing the connection before the query. Allowing you to handle your own connection failures.

```
try {
    Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()->getConnection();
} catch (Zend_Exception $e) {
    throw new Zend_Exception("A different error");
}
```